# SQL Select Data JOIN Filtering Duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql, record

I have record on database :

Table Alternative JOIN to Table Evaluation

```
SELECT a.id_alternative,a.value,a.id_criteria,b.name FROM saw_evaluations AS a JOIN saw_alternatives AS b ON a.id_alternative = b.id_alternative ORDER BY a.id_criteria ASC
```

```
id_alternative|value|id_criterias|name
-----------------------------------------
3|16|1|Mutiya
2|14|1|Restiyanti
2|3|2|Restiyanti
3|3|2|Mutiya
2|2|3|Restiyanti
3|3|3|Mutiya
```

Try with GROUP like this :

```
SELECT a.id_alternative, a.value, a.id_criteria, b.name FROM saw_evaluations AS a JOIN saw_alternatives AS b ON a.id_alternative = b.id_alternative GROUP BY a.id_criteria ORDER BY a.id_criteria ASC
```

```
id_alternative|value|id_criterias|name
-----------------------------------------
3|16|1|Mutiya
3|3|2|Mutiya
3|3|3|Mutiya
```

The problem, I want result data record :

```
id_alternative|value|id_criterias|name
-----------------------------------------
3|16|1|Mutiya
3|3|2|Mutiya
3|3|3|Mutiya
2|14|1|Restiyanti
2|3|2|Restiyanti
2|2|3|Restiyanti
```

please, help to sql query as the result of the data above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `group by` , just `order by col1, col2`

```
SELECT a.id_alternative, a.value, a.id_criteria, b.name 
FROM saw_evaluations AS a 
JOIN saw_alternatives AS b ON a.id_alternative = b.id_alternative 
ORDER BY b.id_alternative desc, a.id_criteria asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without `Group By` and `Order` it

```
SELECT a.id_alternative, a.value, a.id_criteria, b.name 
FROM saw_evaluations AS a JOIN saw_alternatives AS b ON a.id_alternative = b.id_alternative  
ORDER BY a.id_criteria DESC, value DESC
```